# C++11 function object cannot invoke a target, which is another function object

Tags: c++11, functional-programming

I have encountered a program like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

std::function<void ()> foo(){
    const auto s = std::string("bar");
    return [&]{std::cout << s << '\n';};
}

int main()
{
    const auto fun = foo();
    fun();

    return 0;
}
```

I am struggling to understand what is wrong with this program and how to fix it.

My understanding is that `fun` should be able to invoke its target `foo` and print out `bar` but instead there is no output.

I appreciate any helps!

Comment: `s` stops existing when `foo()` returns, so the call to `fun()` accesses a dangling reference. To fix this you can capture by value instead

Comment: You can also make `s` `static`, although I'm not sure that's officially correct.  It appears to work, anyway.